For every n-Riemannian manifold, is every local chart of nonzero radius isometrically embeddable in (n+1)-Euclidean space as Monge patch?
We hear common phrases such as "3-dimensional space curves into 4th dimensional flat space" being thrown around popular science media. And I want to confirm whether such statement is true.
For global embedding, we know this is not the case: e.g. flat torus has no embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
But I have inclination to believe it is true for a "reasonably local case".
Let $M$ be a $n$-Riemannian manifold.
Let $(U \subset \mathbb{R}^n, g)$ be a Riemannian chart,
Set $
g_{ii} = 1+(u_i)^2$ and for $i\neq j, g_{ij}=u_i u_j 
$
This is a system of $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ equations with $n$ variables $u_k$ for $k = 1,\cdots, n$. So at the current state, it is probably not solvable, but I am inclined to believe that a matrix representation of $g$ is congruent to at least 1 such that the system is solvable.
Of course we can use the fact that every positive definite symmetric matrix is congruent to the identity matrix, so every metric at each point on $M$ is Euclidean in a locality in some particular choice of coordinate.
So every Riemannian manifold is Euclidean at each point for "extremely small locality", and there is no knowledge of continuation of the metric beyond any neighborhood of nonzero radius that still guarantees the Monge patch property.
But I am wondering, would it be true for a "reasonably local chart"?
A chart small enough so that the Monge patch $(x_1,\cdots,x_n,u(x_1,\cdots,x_n))$ defined by the function $u:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is still a function (low dimensional intuition I have is, suppose you have a parametrized patch of a regular sphere $(x,y, u(x,y))$, this only goes so far before $u$ curving in on itself), but still of nonzero radius neighborhood?
I'd assume that if this actually is true, proof techniques could be similar to Nash Embedding Theorem.
And suppose the statement is false, I believe that the statement seem to be true for manifolds of dimension 2 and 3.

For smooth metrics on surfaces your conjecture is false, see this post. It is true for real-analytic metrics on surfaces (Burstin-Cartan-Janet Theorem), see Volume 5 of Spivak. The sentence "3-dimensional space curves into 4th dimensional flat space"  is nonsense and you should not waste time trying to make sense out it.

You should state your definitions and question in a more detailed and rigorous manner. I'll try to do this below. Let me know if I misunderstood.
$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$ $M$ is a Riemannian $n$-manifold. You start with a coordinate chart $$ \phi: U \rightarrow M, $$ where $U \subset \R^n$ is open. With respect to the coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$, the Riemannian metric on $M$ is given by $$ g_{ij}\,dx^i dx^j. $$
I believe your question is: Given $x_0 \in U$, does there exist a neighborhood $N \subset U$ of $x_0$ and a scalar function $u: N \rightarrow \R$ such that the map \begin{align*} F: N &\rightarrow \R^{n+1}\\ (x^1, \dots, x^n) &\mapsto (x^1, \dots, x^n, u(x)) \end{align*} is isometric, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
 g_{ij}\,dx^i\,dx^j &= F^*((dx^1)^2+\cdots+(dx^n)^2+(dx^{n+1})^2)\\
&= (dx^1)^2 + \cdots + (dx^n)^2 + (u_1\,dx^1 + \cdots u_n\,dx^n)^2\\
&= (dx^1)^2+\cdots+ (dx^n)^2 + u_iu_j\,dx^i\,dx^j.
\end{align*}
You say that this consists of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ equations, but the number of equations is equal to the number of components of $g$, which is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. The equations can be written as $$ g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + u_iu_j. $$ In general, this has no solution, because it implies that $n-1$ of the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $[g_{ij}]$ are equal to $1$.
In dimension $2$, a more reasonable question is: Given $p_0 \in M$, does there exist local coordinates $(x^1, x^2)$ in a neighborhood $O$ of $p_0$ and a function $u(x^1,x^2)$ such that the map \begin{align*} O &\rightarrow \R^3\\ p &\rightarrow (x^1(p),x^2(p),u(x^1(p),x^2(p))) \end{align*}
is isometric. The difference between this and your question is that here the coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$ are themselves treated as unknown functions on $O$. The number of unknown functions is now $3$, namely $x^1,x^2,u$, and the number of equations is $3$.
As @MosheKahan says, the answer in general is no, due to the counterexample of Nadirashvili and Yuan. If $g$ is real analytic, then the answer is yes. If the Gauss curvature at $p_0$ is nonzero, then the answer is yes. If it is zero, then the answer is known to be yes only under additional assumptions.
In higher dimensions, the number of unknown functions is $n+1$ but the number of equations is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. In these dimensions, it is easy to construct examples of metrics $g$ for which the answer is no.
If, however, you allow $u$ be a map
$$ u: O \rightarrow \R^N, $$
where $$ N \ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}, $$
then the number of unknown functions becomes equal to the number of equations. Here, if $g$ is real analytic, then by the Burstin-Cartan-Janet Theorem, the answer is yes. If $g$ is only smooth and $$N \ge \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, $$ then the relevant part of the proof of Nash's theorem can be used to show that the answer is yes. If $$N = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}, $$ then there are results in dimensions $n = 3, 4$ under suitable assumptions on the curvature tensor at $p_0$. Gromov, in his book Partial Differential Relations, proves the answer is yes in some cases where $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} < N < \frac{n(n+1)}{2}. $$ If $$ N < \frac{n(n-1)}{2}, $$ then the answer is almost always no.
The upshot is that this natural geometric question turns out to be a very nasty system of PDEs, and it is still very poorly understood. You can learn much more about it in the book Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces by Han and Hong.

the book you recommended is a very useful resource
